# Facing some difficulty with recording

Tags: android, checkbox, android-mediarecorder

I have one CheckBox and one button in my application. The CheckBox name is Record meet and start is the name for button. But when I do check my Record meet am making the name of the button from start to stop.

When I check the button the recording will be started and when i stop the button then the recording will be stopped. When I stop the button am again just making the Record meet is enabled and `setChecked(false)`. Because Again I want to do the recording in my application.

Before going back I want to get the recorded files and I want to store it in a file object.

The problem is when i stop the button then it will make enable the checkbox and `setEnable(false)`. When I click again the checkbox then am getting `unfortunately stopped`. The error is pointing in  `myAudioRecorder.prepare()`.

[image]

Could someone help me to solve this problem.

Here is my code.

```
final CheckBox check=(CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recordcheckbox);
    check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             if (isChecked) {
                   shouldRecord=true;
                   toggle.setText("stop");
                   check.setEnabled(false);
                 try {
                     myAudioRecorder.prepare();
                     myAudioRecorder.start();
                  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
                  } 
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 String format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf =new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
                    meet_start=sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                    Log.i("start_time",meet_start);
                } else {

                }

        }
    });
    toggle = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(shouldRecord=false)
            {
            if(toggle.getText().equals("start"))
            {
                String format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
                SimpleDateFormat sdf1 =new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
                start_time = sdf1.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                Log.i("start_time",actualstart);
                toggle.setText("stop");
            }
            }
            else if(shouldRecord=true)
            {
            if(toggle.getText().equals("stop")) 
            {
                shouldRecord = false;
                toggle.setText("start");
                check.setEnabled(true);
                check.setChecked(false);
                String format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
                SimpleDateFormat sdf =new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
                actualend = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                Log.i("end_time",actualend);
                    shouldRecord = false;
                try{
                    myAudioRecorder.stop();
                    myAudioRecorder.release();
                    myAudioRecorder = null;
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.print("error");
                    }
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Recording stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                addRecordingToMediaLibrary();  
            }
            }

        }
    });

public void addRecordingToMediaLibrary() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    long current = System.currentTimeMillis();  
     values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "audio" + file.getName());  
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));  
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");  
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath()); 
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();   
        Uri base = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;  
        Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `myAudioRecorder` to `null` in your `onClick` method. Try either commenting that out or getting a new instance of `myAudioRecorder` in `onCheckedChanged`.

Comment: Titan when i do save then my details will be saved and dialogfragment goes back. So before am going back from my dialogfragment I want to do record multiple times and I want add it in one file object. Could you give me any working example?

Comment: @user3764346, You should accept my answer, if it helped you, and simply open another question if you have another question.

Answer (score -1):

In your try catch block you are doing

```
 myAudioRecorder = null;
```

Try to instantiate that object again when you use it or dont put it at null